# Simple Phone Regxp Return: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im try to make phone validation by custom regExp, but I got this error in console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The phone format will be like this ###-###-####, I have another option like . and prefix..but its work fine until I merge this code...

Html:

```
 <input id="phone"><button id="check">Check</button>
```

JS:

```
var re = /(?:\d{3}|/(\d{3}\))([-|.])\d{3}\1\d{4}\;  

      $("#check").click(function(){
      var OK = re.exec($("#phone").val());  
        if (!OK)  
          window.alert($("#phone").val() + ' isn\'t a phone number with area code!');  
        else
          window.alert('Thanks, your phone number is ' + OK[0]);
      });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13a9ryh5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issue here:

1) You need to replace last char from backslash() to common slash (/)

2) You need to replace second common slash (/) to backslash()

```
var re = /(?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))([-|.])\d{3}\1\d{4}/;
```

[update on your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13a9ryh5/1/)

Read this too for escaping: [regexp escaping](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping)

Comment: Thanks, its resolve issue, but its required to put / in last char in regexp?